# Is $2^{\sqrt{2}} +3^{\sqrt{3}}$ rational?

Tags: soft-question, open-problem

In an exercise found in Lang's *A Complete Course in Calculus*, it's mentioned that it is unknown if $2^{\sqrt{2}} +3^{\sqrt{3}}$ is rational. Has this problem been solved since then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that both $2^{\sqrt2}$ and $3^{\sqrt3}$ are transcendental $($see the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond-Schneider_theorem) for more information$)$, but proving that their sum $($or any other non-trivial linear combination of the two$)$ is also transcendental lies beyond current knowledge. The same goes for $e+\pi$ and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Possibly_transcendental_numbers).

Comment: Is this problem currently of interest to researchers or has it been given up on? And does such a problem fall into the area of field theory?

Comment: @MAM: Let's just put it this way: proving this and [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_conjecture) related open [problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_exponentials_conjecture) is the next logical step.